# Symfony2.7.1 fresh installation. Failed to load resource

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

Symfony2 developers:

Recently, I am planning to get familiar with Symfony2, using it as api project. Current version is v2.7.1.

I already have apache installed as my local environment. So the installation root directory is:

//localhost/symfony

So I followed official guide to install it. Everything looks fine after installation. But when I view the page in development environment (app_dev.php).

//localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php

Page content display as expected, but not styled. Then I open console and find some 404 response as follows:

> Failed to load resource
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/structure.css
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/body.css
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/exception.css
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/structure.css
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/body.css
>
> //localhost/symfony/web/bundles/framework/css/exception.css

I looked into project/web/bundles directory, found nothing inside but two empty file.

framework and sensiodistribution.

Fresh installation without any config change. I got this problem. Could you guys give some explanation why it occurs. Otherwise I didn't get the full package?

Do I miss those files inside project/web/bundles?

If the case in which i missed those file. So could you send me an archive file on current version 2.7.1?

Comment: Don't you need to run 'composer install' or 'composer update' ?

Comment: @YenneInfo I used symfony installer. Not knowing the Smarter assets:install command. Now, it working properly.

Comment: @jack-zheng which operating system are you using? Did the Symfony Installer displayed any error message at the end?

Comment: @JavierEguiluz Windows 8.1. There is no any error at the end. It display installation successfully as expected. I just need to run install command 'app/console assets:install'. I think the step should go into the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If these files exists then you probably have problem with URL Rewriting check your .htaccess or configure your host. You can also use command `php app/console server:start` and check there if it works
2. You can run composer install to install all necessary bundles and libraries and probably composer.json has defined postinstall commands.
3. If you use assetic then you can try to run `php app/console assetic:dump` more on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html
4. In Symfony 2.6 you have new asset manager read more on http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command

`php app/console assets:install` or `php app/console assets:install --symlink`

for Symfony 3.x the directory changed from app to bin so commands are:

`php bin/console assets:install` or `php bin/console assets:install --symlink`

Comment: You get to the point. Not only solved my problem, but also in detail. Symfony2 is getting more and more full-featured. Diffrent from any other frameworks. I am about to read though the documentation.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please accept one of answers so question can be closed. You can read cookbook and book there are plenty of examples of most common issues

Answer (score 6):

You must run the command `app/console assets:install` to generate symlinks (or files) in `/web/bundles`

Comment: That's the point. New feature since 2.6. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Since I landed here from a Symfony 3 search this might be useful for Symfony 3 users having the same problem

Run php `bin/console assets:install` at the project root